# C Wire - Williamson Furnace/Honeywell Thermostat

Tags: hvac, furnace, thermostat-c-wire

I'm trying to install a new wifi thermostat, but am a little confused. I have 5 wires, but none are connected to the C in the thermostat, as seen below:
[image: thermostat]

Additionally, when I trace the thermostat to inside of the Williamson furnace, it appears that the yellow/white wires are the ones connected to transformers, as seen below:
[image: furnace]

And here is the thermostat wire hooking into the "panel":
[image: thermostatconn]

Is there a configuration of the existing wiring I can use to power the new thermostat? (I've also purchased a 24v transformer, but am unsure of how to complete the circuit if I add one of the wires to the C terminal.)

Wiring diagrams below:
[image: wiring diagrams]

Comment: Can you post the wiring diagram for your furnace please? It should be on a label on the inside of the access cover or such...

Comment: Can you get us more photos of the wiring at the furnace please? The last installer left us with a bowl o' spaghetti to sort out

Comment: if that's the thermostat cable in the middle of the second photo I can't see how it ever worked,

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - Noting that Jasen (thanks Jasen!) said it couldn't work, I located where the thermostat wire connects. It's in the picture above, but not easy to get a good pic of b/c the fan blocks access to it.

Comment: @sorrell -- hm, did the installer add that terminal strip? I can't match it up with either of the strips on the factory wiring diagram...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel All I know about the furnace is that it’s old... is there any way to hook up the new thermostat utilizing a separate two-wire 24v transformer? If so what configuration would I use on the new thermostat (Honeywell RTH9585WF1004)

Comment: @sorrell -- some more photos of the wiring would help us unravel this